# How to change ffmpeg filters on the fly

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible with ffmpeg, on the commandline, to change filters such as brightness, saturation or gamma, while ffmpeg is running, **from outside ffmpeg (e.g. from a php/node/ruby script)**? (on the fly / dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

The `eq` filter which sets brightness, contrast, saturation and gamma doesn't seem to work in timeline editing mode.

`colorlevels` and `curves` *are* compatible if you think you can use them to achieve your desired result.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "curves=enable='between(t,0,5)':preset=darker, colorlevels=enable='between(t,5,10)':romin=0.5:gomin=0.5:bomin=0.5" ...
```

where `t` is the time in seconds.

The `curves` filter can even use a Photoshop curves file (`*.asf`).

Comment: Seems timeline editing supports only enabling/disabling filters when one runs ffmpeg. I want to do it dynamically, see edited question.